# Difference between ь and ъ

Tags: алфавит

What is the difference between ь and ъ? Why do Russians use these letters?

Comment: It is interesting that in 1964 there was a project of [russian orthography reform](http://magazines.russ.ru/nz/2010/3/ka19-pr.html) (not implemented though) that suggested to remove letter Ъ and always use Ь instead

Comment: why do Spanish speaking people use ñ and ll ?

Comment: btw, the fact that 'подьячий' is so often misspelled demonstrates it very well that softness/hardness of consonants before iotized vowels has lost its importance.

Comment: Because they don't want to copy Italian speaking ones using gn and gl! :)

Comment: "Why do Russians use these letters?" What is that supposed to mean? They are a part of alphabet and have their function like any other letter. Are you asking "what is their purpose?"

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy ну вот не знаю - слово подьезд и подъезд звучат по-разному - я бы на месте реформантов сдался бы и писал подйезд и подйачий

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried reading about them? On wiki, for example: [Russian alphabet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet), [Ъ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AA), [Ь](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign)
Your second question does not make sense, really. They are used because they must be used for the correct spelling.

Comment: So they are only used only for a correct spelling? Nothing more? Like accents?

Comment: You are ignoring the links. Read them first, then if you have any further questions - ask.

Comment: Yes, read the links first. No, they are actually used for correct pronunciation.

Comment: I think this is a better link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yer

Answer (score 4):

Твёрдый знак выполняет в русском языке **разделительную функцию** — указывает, что *после согласного йотированная гласная буква обозначает не мягкость согласного, а два звука*: я — [й’а], е — [й’э], ё — [й’о], ю — [й’у] (объять [абй’́ат’], съест [сй’эст], съёмка [сй’́омка]).

Функции мягкого знака сложнее. Он имеет в русском языке три функции — **разделительную, функцию обозначения самостоятельной мягкости парных согласных, грамматическую функцию**:

1. Мягкий знак может выполнять аналогичную разделительную функцию перед я, ю, е, ё, и внутри слова не после приставки (вьюга, соловьиный) и в некоторых иноязычных словах перед о: (бульон, компаньон).
2. Мягкий знак может служить для обозначения самостоятельной мягкости парного согласного на конце слова и в середине слова перед согласным:конь, банька.
3. Мягкий знак после непарного по твёрдости / мягкости согласного может выполнять грамматическую функцию — пишется по традиции в определённых грамматических формах, не неся никакой фонетической нагрузки (ср.: ключ — ночь, учится — учиться). При этом мягкий знак не обозначает мягкости не только у непарных твёрдых, но и у непарных мягких согласных.

Comment: Врядли это как-то поможет автору вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Both letters change the pronuncation of preceding and/or succeeding letter.

Мягкий знак (ь) смягчает предшествующую согласную (а если она должна быть мягкой из-за того, что после неё стоит е,ё,и,ю,я , то она мягкой и остаётся). Если за мягким знаком следует гласная, она йотируется.

Твёрдый знак (ъ) делает предшествующую согласную твёрдой и йотирует следующую за ним гласную.

Что такое смягчать согласную? Послушайте слова `кон` и `конь` и сравните звучание буквы `н`.  Сравните звучание буквы `л` в словах `больно` и `полно`.

Что такое йотировать гласную?  Сравните звучание буквы `я` в словах `Коля` и `колья`, буквы `е` в словах `въезд` и `весть`.

Comment: *"Делает твердой"* - это неверно. Согласные твердые по умолчанию (а с всегда мягкими твердый знак не используется). У твердого знака есть только разделительная функция.

Comment: В слове подъезд д твёрдое, потому что твёрдый знак. Без него д было бы мягким.

Comment: А слово `Коля` без буквы `л` писалось бы как `Коя`. И что теперь - буква `л` убирает йотирование с гласной?

Comment: @user31264 Вы путаете причину и следствие. В слове "подъезд" нужно писать твердый знак, потому что там твердое "д", а не там твердое "д", потому что пишется с твердым знаком.

Comment: Last two sentences (about different pronouciation) are not very useful for many people whose native language differ from slavic - they cannot hear the difference (at least at very eary stages of learning Russian) between "кон" and "конь" etc.

Comment: @Abakan - откуда мы знаем, что там твёрдое д?  Оттуда, что стоит твёрдый знак.  Что касается слов "кон" и "конь", их произношение можно найти в en.wiktionary.org  .  Или об этом ресурсе изучающие русский язык тоже не знают?

Comment: @user31264 Дети и неграмотные старушки тоже знают что там твёрдый знак? Что касается произношения, то знать ресурс и *слышать* разницу - разные, несвязанные друг с другом  вещи. Многие, очень многие носители русского языка, изучающие другие языки, не слышат разницы между длинными и короткими гласными, а также между открытыми и закрытыми, хотя знают десяток-другой ресурсов с произношением.

Comment: По-моему, вы спорите, чтобы спорить.

Comment: @Abakan user31264 прав, если русский язык для него не родной (или же он говорит с точки зрения человека, изучающего русский как иностранный). В этом случае, действительно, наличие Ъ в слове _подъезд_ позволяет (иностранцу) узнать, что "д" - твёрдое.  Вы же совершенно правы, если речь идёт о человеке, овладевшем русским в детстве - даже если он не умеет писать/читать, он будет произносить твёрдое "д", так как знает, что это слово звучит именно так.

Comment: My own perception is such that in modern Russian, consonants preceding 'ъ' tend to be pronounced softly. I can think of no word where hard vs soft pronunciation at the end of a prefix may result in change of meaning. Thus, in modern Russian, the usage of 'ъ' is purely orthographical.

Comment: @Andrey Chernyakhovskiy I never heard them pronounced softly. In подъезд it is hard, and pronouncing it soft is either dialect or baby speak.

Comment: @Andrey Chernyakhovskiy подьячий = vice-deacon, подъячий = something intended to be under a yak.

Comment: @Anixx, I have never seen or heard an authentic usage of 'подъячий' and cannot imagine a context in which this word might be useful. Looks like, from practical point of view that's an irrelevant word. However, I found a surname 'Подъячий' (obviously a distortion), and that gave me an idea that 'ъ' may be important for some transliterations.

Comment: @Anixx, Btw, the fact that 'подьячий' is so often misspelled demonstrates it very well that softness/hardness of consonants before iotized vowels has lost its importance.

Comment: @Anixx >I never heard them pronounced softly.  I can _imagine_ a soft 'д' in _подъезд_, just like _сосиски_ is pronounced by some people as _сосисЬки_ but, indeed, this is a dialect (old Moscow dialect, I believe). I, for one, always pronounce a hard 'д'.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev, One can deny that consonants before 'ъ' may be pronounced softer than normal hard consonants; but it is then true that consonants before 'ь' + vowel are pronounced harder than normal soft consonants. In either case, to me, the beginnings of 'подъязычный' vs 'подьяк', 'съезд' vs 'Сьерра-Невада', 'конъюктивит' vs 'в Конью' as pronounced by a typical Russian these days, sound indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Well, in practice (I mean from pronunciation point of view) there's no special difference between `Ь`, `Ъ`, especially concerning `Ъ`. From time to time there's discussion to completely remove letter `Ъ` and replace it everywhere with `Ь`
2. From the other hand correct spelling of these letters is considered as a sign of literate/educated person.

So if you don't care about what kind of impression you do have on others - replace `Ъ` with `Ь` and forget about problem. If one is a foreigner - it's excusable and understandable.

Otherwise read carefully rules and use letters accordingly.

Comment: This is absolutely, blatantly and patently false. The soft sign and hard sign have completely different purposes.